# NSScrollView messes up NSGradient (corruption)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsgradient

I have a custom box that I've made that is a subclass of `NSBox`.  I override the `drawRect:` method and draw a gradient in it like this (assuming I already have a `start` & `end` color):

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:start endingColor:end];
    [gradient drawInRect:dirtyRect angle:270];
    [gradient release];
}
```

Now this box is added as a subview of a prototype view for a `NSCollectionView`.  In the view's original state it looks like this:

[image]

And after scrolling the view out of sight and back in again, it looks like this:

[image]

Why is my gradient getting corrupted like that, and how can I fix it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're drawing in `dirtyFrame`, not the entire rectangle of the box. I have no idea if this is correct, but try this:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:start endingColor:end];
    [gradient drawInRect:[self bounds] angle:270];
    [gradient release];
}
```

Comment: You win the prize.  Just needed to call `[gradient drawInRect:[self bounds] angle:270];` and it fixed the problem.  Thanks!  I'll accept it when it's availible.

Comment: I'll update it to `[self bounds]` rather than `[self frame]`, I suppose, then.

Comment: Okay.  I'll ask you the same question I asked Bavarious, namely is there a better place to be drawing this instead of in `drawRect:`?

Comment: @sudo: Probably not. As far as I know, it will only be called when a previously-hidden part of the view is revealed, like when you scroll it back into view. If it's scrolled within the view or scrolled out but not back in, I don't think it will be called, so it should be fairly efficient.

Answer (score 3):

That `dirtyRect` argument doesn’t necessarily represent the entire box. If Cocoa decides that only a subframe of the original frame needs (re)drawing, `dirtyRect` represents only that subframe. If you’ve drawn a gradient for the entire frame and then (re)draw the same gradient for a subframe, it's likely they won't match.

Try:

```
[gradient drawInRect:[self bounds] angle:270];
```

instead.

One further note: it looks like your gradient object could be cached instead of being created/released inside `-drawRect:`.

Comment: I figured it out just when you posted it.  Thanks!